# excepton raised while running a jar created using gradle/springboot/intellij

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, build.gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

below is the content of my `build.gradle` file and the error i get.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why on earth the maven plugins, you are using maven. Stop mixing versions of spring. Also post as code as images become unreadable (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information on how to ask as good question). Also you don't explain *how* you are creating the jar file.

Comment: i had mentioned everything in details and pasted thee code instead of image, but stackoverflow did not allow to post the code saying formatting issues. so just tried with image, it got posted. ignore the maven plugins, the error is still the same without them. mixing versions of spring(corrected but same error). Jar creation (using intellij , gradle tool window, tasks- build-jar).

Comment: Fix your formatting then instead of posting unreadable images. Also you are using Spring boot and in your gradle file try very hard not to. Remove the jar part from your build file. The spring boot plugin is just for that ( I strongly suggest a read of the documentation which explains all this).

Comment: Thanks. Removing the jar part worked.